# echo $PATH not displaying all paths when logged in from different environments on same account

Tags: ubuntu, assembla

When I run echo $PATH as root from 2 different scenarios to the same server I get a different result.

Firstly I ssh via term as root where I installed kitchen. When I type

```
$ which kitchen
$ usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/kitchen
$ echo $PATH
```

I can see it correctly listed at the end

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/bin:/usr/local  
/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:    
/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/local/rvm/bin:
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/kitchen
```

I'm using my assembla host to run the SSH script (also specifying root) and when I run

```
$ which kitchen
$ Process exited with: 1. Reason was:  ()
$ echo $PATH
$ /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:
  /usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

Using Ubuntu 14.04

I would like to know how to get the same output when running from assembla account as when logged in over terminal if possible

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely the difference between having an interactive shell and not having an interactive shell.

Different environment files will be read depending on your setup, take a look at your .bashrc or .profile

From the bash man page:

> Bash attempts to determine when it is being run with its standard input
>   connected to a a network  connection,  as  if  by  the remote shell daemon,
>   usually rshd, or the secure shell daemon sshd.  If bash
>   determines it is being run in this fashion, it reads and executes commands
>   from  ~/.bashrc,  if  that file  exists and is readable.

Basically, run `grep -r kitchen ~/.*" to determine which file is adding kitchen to your PATH variable, then you will be able to determine if that file is being read when you ssh with a non-interactive terminal.

You can always set your PATH before you run your script as well:

export PATH=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/kitchen:${PATH}

P.S. in your output, it looks like your PATH variable has a newline in it, it should not.

Comment: Thanks for that, set me in a good direction. I ended up putting "source /etc/profile" at the start of my script and its up and running.